# Displaying src of image inside an iframe with selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe

I am trying to download an image automatically from shapeNet using Python and selenium. I am almost there but the last step evades me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "yourproxy")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", number_of_port)
#browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.shapenet.org/taxonomy-viewer')
#Page is long to load
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='02958343_anchor']")))
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='02958343_anchor']")
linkElem.click()
#Page is also long to display iframe
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "model_3dw_bcf0b18a19bce6d91ad107790a9e2d51")))
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_id("model_3dw_bcf0b18a19bce6d91ad107790a9e2d51")
linkElem.click()
#iframe slow to be displayed
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'viewerIframe')))
```

Until now everything runs smoothly we are into the iframe. The next line works but I have to use a time.sleep() to make it work it is slightly ugly but I do not know of any alternative and it is not the core of my question:

```
import time
#does not work have to use time.sleep
#element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h4")))
time.sleep(20)
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h4")
linkElem.click()
```

Now I want to download one of the images just displayed in the collapse menu opened by my click so I found its xpath using developper tools:

```
img = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/span/img")
src = img.get_attribute('src')
```

And now it can access img but src is None until I click manually on the webpage. Why is that ? What am I doing wrong ?

PS: the last step would be:

```
os.system("wget %s --no-check-certificate"%src)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/span/img")`, you can use the following `xpath` :

```
img = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]//div[@class='searchResult' and @id='image.3dw.bcf0b18a19bce6d91ad107790a9e2d51.0']/img[@class='enlarge']")
src = img.get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I upvoted ! Would you care to elaborate your answer ? Like how it is that it works and the other does not ?Inspecting the html it looks like the class is imageResult not searchResult no ? I cannot see how you found out the id of the image to ? Plus what does the class enlarge means ? Is it to zoom in on the picture ? So many questions !

Comment: Well, first of all I must admit your detailed code helped me to get to the bottom of your your issue but you could have more verbose in specifying your manual steps. Second, though absolute `xpath` but still you are lucky enough to get through till `xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h4")`. This is where you loosened your control. I didn't wanted to repeat the absolute `xpath` way, so I did a `//div` and dived into my business area with `class` as `searchResult` and grabbed the sibling `<image>` tag to pull out the `src` attribute. I don't have any idea what class enlarge means but it is there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I will try to modify my question so it is more precise. I'll accept your answer in the mean time I will work through it one more time next week to be sure I understood all the steps correctly !